# Q Reject promise within .then success callback

Tags: node.js, promise, q

I'm using kriskowal Q promise library in a node app.
I have code that reads a file and then attempts to parse part of it into a Javascript Date object (I have similar code in other places that attempts to do a JSON.parse). In these circumstances I've read and personally feel it's best practice to wrap that code in a try/catch block to avoid and potentially fatal surprises. Here's some real code mixed with psuedo code:

```
var getMonitorTimestamp = function() {
    return readLogFile()
        .then(
            function ok(contents) {
                //regex to capture dates in format of: 09 Jan 2015 09:42:01
                var regex = /[0-9]{2} [\w]{3} [0-9]{4} ([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}/g;
                var timestamp = contents.match(regex)[0];
                var date;
                try {
                    date = new Date(timestamp);
                    return date;
                }
                //when I've caught the error here, how do I reject the promise?
                //this will still return an error to the next success callback in the queue
                catch(e) {
                    console.error(e);
                    return e;
                }

            },
            function err(e) {
                console.error(e);
                return new Error();
            }
        );
};


exports.sendRes = function(req, res) {
    getMonitorTimestamp()
        .then(
            function yay(data) {
                //don't want to send an error here
                res.json({result: data});
            },
            function boo(e) {
                res.status(500).json({error: e});
            }
        );
}
```

As you can see, it would be useful to reject the promise in the getMonitorTimstamp->ok callback because it failed.

Is there a way to do that in Q? I haven't found anything (yet). Or is there a different pattern for handling this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually covered in the q docs under the section [Handling Errors](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#handling-errors).

Instead of using the `.then(success, fail)` style, you'll want to chain your handlers to allow the success handler to `throw` to the fail handler.

```
readLogFile()
  .then(function yay(data) {
    throw "Eek!";
  })
  .fail(function boo(e) {
    res.status(500).json({error: e});
  });
```

Comment: Although in real life never throw strings :D

Comment: Guilty :P wanted to keep the example as small as I could!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to catch the exceptions in your `then`functions if you use this construction (as discussed in the [Q documentation](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#handling-errors)):

```js
function a () {
  return methodThatReturnsAPromise().then(function () {
     // Exceptions can happen here
  })
}

a()
  .then(function () { /* Success */ })
  .catch(function (err) { /* Error */ })
```

The exceptions will be propagated to the receiver of the promise.

As for your code:

You are covered for exceptions, but if you find an error condition (not caused by a exception) you can return a **new rejected promise** in your `readLogFile().then(...` function:

```js
var getMonitorTimestamp = function() {
  return readLogFile()
    .then(function (contents) {
       if (<check errors here>) {
          // Found the error condition
          return Q.reject(‘Failed here’)
       } else {
          // Return the normal result
          ...
          return date
       }
    })
}
```

And leave a single `catch` clause at the topmost level of your code:

```js
exports.sendRes = function(req, res) {
    getMonitorTimestamp()
        .then(function (data) {
            res.json({result: data})
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            res.status(500).json({error: e})
        })
}
```